# Enabling XLA JIT from tf.slim

Tags: python, tensorflow

One way of turning on the Tensorflow XLA JIT is to use `tf.OptimizerOptions.ON_1` flag, by passing it to the TF session, similar to the following lines in python:

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.graph_options.optimizer_options.global_jit_level = tf.OptimizerOptions.ON_1  
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
```

However, I'm not sure when/how to enable XLA JIT when I utilize the Slim library instead (I use `slim.learning.train` to start the training).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`slim.learning.train` takes a `session_config` argument to which you can pass the `ConfigProto`.

Comment: Did you mean `slim.learning.train` or the `slim.training.train` is a new addition in TF?